# Generalized Mersenne Prime Conjecture Combined $(a,b)$ pair

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

As read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Other_generalized_Mersenne_primes), it is conjectured that for and pair of integers $(a,b)$ that are coprime, not perfect ${r^{\text{th}}}$ powers, and $-4ab$ is not a perfect ${4^{\text{th}}}$ power, then there should be infinitely many primes of the form $(a^n-b^n)/(a-b)$. In other words, there are infinitely many primes $n$ such that $(a^n-b^n)/(a-b)$ is prime for when the above conditions are met.

I am unsure however, when taking two $(a,b)$ pairs, say $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ are there infinitely many primes $n$ such that *both* $(a^n-b^n)/(a-b)$ and $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$ are prime for. In my words, are the exponents $n$ for which $(a^n-b^n)/(a-b)$ and $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$ are prime for overlap infinitely many times? Can anyone support or not support this with a few reasons? 
Example: Do these sequences in OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A000043) and [here](https://oeis.org/A057468) overlap infinitely many times?

Comment: Interesting question, but we probably only can get statistical heuristics supporting the truth or not. I think it will be already difficult to show that at least one prime $n$ exists for each choice of pairs.